# Android Studio: Why isn't my list view populated by DB sorting properly?

Tags: android, database, sorting, listview, android-contentprovider

Happy new year,

I have a database which is created locally when the app is run.  It has various fields, but I can't seem to get my DB to sort correctly.

I have a content provider, and the query function is below:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strings, String s, String[] strings1, String s1) {
    Cursor c;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case PICTURES:
            //c = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, DBOpenHelper.ALL_COLUMNS, s, null, null, null, DBOpenHelper.PIC_ARTIST + " ASC");
            c = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, DBOpenHelper.ALL_COLUMNS, s, null, null, null, null);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return c;
}
```

I have an activity which contains a listView which is populated by the DB items.  When I click a button, it should sort on one of the fields Alphabetically Ascending, but nothing happens

```
private CursorAdapter sortTitle() {
    if(c != null) {
        c.close();
        c = getContentResolver().query(PicturesProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,DBOpenHelper.PIC_TITLE + " ASC");
    } else {
        c = getContentResolver().query(PicturesProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,DBOpenHelper.PIC_TITLE + " ASC");
    }
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return cursorAdapter;
}
```

am I doing something wrong that is obvious here ?

Thanks in advance.

I've kept the code pasted here to a minimum, so if anything is missing just let me know.

Comment: why do have if else block as the same sorting? is it a mistake ? private CursorAdapter sortTitle() {
    if(c != null) {
        c.close();
        c = getContentResolver().query(PicturesProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,DBOpenHelper.PIC_TITLE + " ASC");
    } else {
        c = getContentResolver().query(PicturesProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,DBOpenHelper.PIC_TITLE + " ASC");
    }
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return cursorAdapter;
}

Comment: It's not a mistake, I'm just closing the cursor with c.close if it's open when you click the update button.